# best media player to run .m3u8 kind of media file and to save played movie time iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone

Actually my client is sending movie url is definsts/mp4/low/mp4:.mp4/playlist.m3u8">http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/vod/*definsts*/mp4/low/mp4:.mp4/playlist.m3u8 so i just want to know that what should be the best media player to run such media file and i also required to save played movie time so that i can run played movie from paused time, not from beginning.
Thanks in advance
all you developers are rocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you use the MPMoviePlayerController to play the movie.  It will correctly handle the streams identified by the .m3u8.

MPMoviePlayerController implements the MPMediaPlayback protocol, which includes a read/write property named currentPlaybackTime.

You can read the time from currentPlaybackTime when the user stops or pauses the movie and save that value. Later, when the user wants to continue watching from that same point, you simply set currentPlaybackTime to that saved value.